# How to update Unity prefab dynamically?

Tags: unity-game-engine

1) How can I find the height of a prefab?  In my code below I'd like to make the 232 value dynamic, so I can safely update my prefab in the future.

2) How can I get a reference to a Text object in my rendered prefab?

```
Player[] players = JsonHelper.getJsonArray<Player>(www.downloadHandler.text);

float nextY = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
{
    Player player = players[i];

    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(0, -nextY, spawnPoint.position.z);

    GameObject spawnedItem = Instantiate(listViewItem, pos, spawnPoint.rotation);

    nextY += 232;

    // spawnedItem.?  <- need to put a Player name into a Text in here

    spawnedItem.transform.SetParent(spawnPoint, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a c# script that will be your interface between your prefab and other components, something as such :

```
public class MyCustomPrefab : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializedField] private float height;
    [SerializedField] private TextMeshProUGUI text;

    // other variable, methods, anything you want

}
```

Then instead of instantiating it as a GameObject, use your Type :

```
MyCustomPrefab prefab = Instantiate(.....);

// Then you can access/use any variable/method that you want
nextY += prefab.height;
prefab.text = .....;
```

Comment: Where does your reference come from ? It needs to be of type MyCustomPrefab aswell (or if you really can't, just use GetComponent)

Comment: @gdonald `Instantiate` returns the type of the passed prefab. Either as Jichael said make your prefab field of type `MyCustomPrefab` or use `MyCustomPrefab prefab = Instantiate(.....).GetComponent<MyCustomPrefab>();` I would really advice to stick to the later though since this also adds an additional security for the Inspector itself: You only can reference something that actually has that component attached!

Comment: @Jichael I would not call the instance variable `prefab`, that's a bit confusing. Better call it `instance` or something similar

Comment: @gdonald sorry I meant ofcourse **NOT** stick to the later but stick to the first! ^^